# decrypt an encrypted value?

Tags: c#, encryption, character-encoding

I have an old [Paradox database](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paradox_%28database%29) (I can convert it to Access 2007) which contains more then 200,000 records. This database has two columns: the first one is named "Word" and the second one is named "Mean". It is a dictionary database and my client wants to convert this old database to ASP.NET and SQL.

However, we don't know what key or method is used to encrypt or encode the "Mean" column which is in the Unicode format. The software itself has been written in Delphi 7 and we don't have the source code. My client only knows the credentials for logging in to database. The problem is decoding the Mean column.

What I do have is the compiled windows application and the Paradox database. This software can decode the "Mean" column for each "Word" so the method and/or key is in its own compiled code(.exe) or one of the files in its directory.

For example, we know that in the following row the "Zymurgy" 
exactly means "مبحث عمل تخمیر در شیمی علمی, تخمیر شناسی" since the application translates it like that. Here is what the record looks like when I open the database in Access:

```
Word      Mean
Zymurgy   5OBnGguKPdDAd7L2lnvd9Lnf1mdd2zDBQRxngsCuirK5h91sVmy0kpRcue/+ql9ORmP99Mn/QZ4=
```

Therefore we're trying to discover how the value in the Mean column is converted to "مبحث عمل تخمیر در شیمی علمی, تخمیر شناسی". I think the "Mean" column value in above row is encoded in Base64 string format, but decoding the Base64 string does not yet result in the expected text.

The extensions for files in the win app directory are dll, CCC, DAT, exe (other than the main app file), SYS, FAM, MB, PX, TV, VAL.

Any kind of help is appreciated.

here is two more example and remember double quotes at start and end are not part of the strings:

```
word: "abdominal" 
coded value: "vwtj0bmj7jdF9SS8sbrIalBoKMDvTbpraFgG4gP/G9GLx5iU/E98rQ==" 
translation in Farsi: "شکمی, بطنی, وریدهای شکمی, ماهیان بطنی" 
word: "cart" 
coded value: "KHoCkDsIndb6OKjxVxsh+Ti+iA/ZqP9sz28e4/cQzMyLI+ToPbiLOaECWQ8XKXTz" 
translation in Farsi: "ارابه, گاری, دوچرخه, چرخ, با گاری بردن"
```

here is the result in different encodings:

```
1- in unicode the result is: "ᩧ訋퀽矀箖�柖�섰᱁艧껀늊螹泝汖銴岔꫾也捆￉鹁" 
2- in utf32 the result is: "��������������" 
3- in utf7 the result is: "äàg\v=ÐÀw²ö{Ýô¹ßÖg]Û0ÁAgÀ®²¹ÝlVl´\\¹ïþª_NFcýôÉÿA" 
4- in utf8 the result is: "��g\v�=��w���{����g]�0�Ag��������lVl���\\����_NFc����A�" 
5- in 1256 the result is: "نàg\vٹ=ذہw²ِ–{فô¹كضg]غ0ءAg‚ہ®ٹ²¹‡فlVl´’”\\¹ï‏ھ_NFc‎ôةےA"
```

yet i discovered that the paradox database system is very complex when it comes to key management and most of the time the keys are "compound keys" and that's why it's problematic and that's why it's abandoned!

**UPDATE:** i'm trying to do the automation by using AutoIt v3 because the decryption process  as i understand can't be done in one or two days. now i have another problem which is related to text/font. when i copy the translated text to notepad it will change to some unrecognizable text unless i change the font of notepad to the font of the translation software. if i type something in the notepad in Farsi it will show it correctly regardless of what font i've been chosen. more interesting is when i copy the text to any other program like MS Office Word it'll be shown correctly no matter what font i choose.

so how can i get around this ?

Comment: How did you get the meaning of the word "zymurgy" from the "win app"?

Comment: This looks like a nice challenge. But we need more info. What is your base-64 decoding of the "Mean" string, in hex? What unicode characters are you expecting? (Also, this is encoding/decoding, not encryption/decryption.)

Comment: Try this, http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/

Then save string in a unicode text file and take a look on result.

Comment: It's not utf8, utf16 or any of the three common arabic encodings.  If you're trying to extract the database from a commercial translation app it may well be obfuscated.

Comment: I notice its length is a multiple of 8 bytes when decoded. Are all the entries a multiple of 8 bytes?

Comment: I don't think it is unicode. Decoding the base64 yields 56 Bytes. Any unicode encoding for the string takes more data. So lets assume some localized encoding with 8 Bit per character. The string has a length of 40 Characters, so 16 Bytes remain. I think there is some kind of encryption or obfuscation (there are 7 spaces, but no byte repeats more than 3 times and the data seems somewhat random). The 16 Bytes may be a key or an encoding specifier? How about trying to disassemble the executable (might reveal Crypto-API calls/"secret" keys)?

Comment: what makes you believe that the data is encrypted? Why should a dictionary be encrypted? I am asking because it may send you in a wrong path

Comment: See the plotted data: [link](http://www.abload.de/img/datavbwo.png). The upper graph shows the strings encoded with CP1256 (for all three samples). You can see the spaces and commas separated in the lower region. The lower graph shows the decoded base64 values. Apart from the odd padding, they seem to be fairly random. So I suspect some obfuscation or maybe compression. I have no idea however, why anyone would do that. Maybe its compressed UTF32 or something like that? That would at least make some sense.

Comment: Can't you just write a screen scraper application that drives the original application, enters one word at a time and copies the result. or try [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/) or similar.

Comment: what about reverse engineer the app looking for the algorithm? then just copy it

Comment: Hey Jim , I am pretty sure I can decrypt the strings for you and write a routine you can use. If decryption is still an option, you can contact me: MrWhite12 [at] web.de

Answer (score 3):

In this situation, I would think about writing a script/program to simply pull all the data out through the existing program.

You could write an application to send keypresses to the app which would select and copy each value in turn.

It would take a while to run, but you could just leave it overnight (how big is your database?) and it only has to run once.

Not sure how easy this would be, since I haven't seen this app of course - might this work?

Comment: I agree. If the database is not too big, this might likely be the simplest solution. Try to scrape the data and simply write it into a new database/table as plain old Unicode (UTF16 is probably the best here). Just make sure, that nothing goes amiss.

Answer (score 2):

Take a debugger like ollydbg/softice. Find the place where the mean is decoded/encoded and then step through the instructions one by one, check all registers to find out what is done. I have done so numerous times. That should help you getting started, since you have the application which is able to decode this stuff. You also have a reference word. That's all you need.

Also take into consideration: Unicode can be Little or Big Endian. So you might try swapping the bytes. UTF-8 can be a pain, since some words are stored as one byte and some as two bytes.

You can also try to take words which are almost identical in Farsi and try to compare the outputs. That could lead to a reconstruction of a custom code page, if there is one.